# É possível juntar o OwlCarousel ao Highcharts?

Tags: mobile, highcharts, slider

Eu tenho um `slider` feito pelo `OwlCarousel` quero que passem gráficos de pizza renderizados pelo `HighCharts`. Ou seja, Eu tenho 4 `pie charts` Com legendas, e quero que ao passar os `4 pies`, fiquem também sem a legenda apenas em Mobile.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pedropcruz/0hv2cjjz/23/

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível, você já esta trabalhando com `div's`, basta coloca-las todas dentro de uma outra `div` e adicionar as `class` que criam esse efeito....

### USANDO O FLICKITY

```
<div class="main-gallery">
    <div id="DonuTchartIBV-MMS-1" class="donut gallery-cell"></div>
    ...
    <div id="" class="gallery-cell"></div>
</div>
```

E claro, carregar as bibliotecas necessárias e adicionar a seguinte linha no seu arquivo `.js`:

```
$('.main-gallery').flickity({
  cellAlign: 'left',
  contain: true
});
```

[jsFiddle do exemplo usando o flickity](http://jsfiddle.net/0hv2cjjz/24/)

### USANDO O OWLCAROUSEL

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
    <div id="DonuTchartIBV-MMS-1" class="donut"></div>
    ...
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Carregar as bibliotecas: [Theme.css](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css), [carousel.css](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css), [carousel.js](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js) necessárias e adicionar a seguinte linha no seu arquivo `.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
});
```

[jsFiddle do exemplo usando o OwlCarousel](http://jsfiddle.net/sqf4sxxo/)

Comment: Consegui por, mas estou a usar slides diferentes, e achei mais eficaz o Owl Carousel. Consegui por a funcionar, mas não me mostra os gráficos e não entendo o porquê. Poderei partilhar aqui a minha dúvida?

Comment: editado, vê se compreendes-te. é um pouco dificil explicar para mim.

Comment: Mais ou menos como isto que tenho na print:

http://prntscr.com/7co09m

Até está tudo bem. Mas quando escrevo os gráficos (Highcharts) Ele não mexe o slider (e tem autoplay: 1000) e não existe efeitos nem nada. Só quando faço resize ele actua normalmente. Queria que ele ao ter aquela div naquele "display" ele escreva os gráficos e que ponha o OwlCarousel. Vou tentar expor no fiddle e já mostro :)

Comment: Mostra os gráficos, os valores que tenho no meio e o slider. Mas tudo parado, sem qualquer tipo de animação.

Comment: Já pus e também comentei. É dificil explicar para mim.

Comment: Bem, eu estou a fazer 2 highcharts, mas na verdade o mesmo mudando apenas o facto de ter Legenda ou não. vê o meu fiddle, não consigo perceber onde tou a falhar... http://jsfiddle.net/pedropcruz/7xs5t848/4/

Comment: Acredito que o erro esteja no gráfico, não no carousel.....  vou dar uma olhada no seu fiddle, ver se encontro o erro

Comment: O HighCharts funciona normalmente sem o slider?

Comment: sim funciona! Para perceberes o que me acontece: http://prntscr.com/7cph59 Se fizer um resize: http://prntscr.com/7cphef ou seja, já está agir bem

Comment: tem como voce colocar no fiddle somente a parte do gráfico?

Comment: Sim já está no fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/pedropcruz/7xs5t848/4/